# Presenting with beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set the beamer pdf version of a presentation as something similar to that of microsoft powerpoint whereby the click of a mouse will allow one to switch to the next slide (the method of presentation that I am using is adobe and so I am looking to get some advice if this is achievable).

Thank you

Comment: You can at least use the left and right arrows to navigate through the pdf during your presentation. Depending on the pdf viewer, this can also be done by mouse click.

Comment: I've tested with SumatraPDF and works like you want.

Comment: I suggest buying a remote. I have the Logitech R400 and it makes it very easy to present with either SumatraPDF, PDF X-Change or any other pdf viewer.

Comment: You could use the space key or the scrolling wheel on your mouse. Here on a Linux system the left mouse key for moving forward through the presentation works fine.

Comment: If you want, you can also make it automatic with \begin{frame} \transduration{1.5} blablabla \end{frame}

Comment: Doesn't this just work out of the box, without having to do anything? (It does on Linux at least, though that version of Adobe Reader is somewhat old I think.) It only works in fullscreen mode of course.

Comment: It also works out of the box with recent versions of Adobe Reader, e.g. XI